# How to access req.user data members in passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am trying to use passport.js to authenticate users.  I can successfully log in but after login, I am unable to access the data memebers of req.user, even though req.user appears to exist and posses the correct data.

I am able to run `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.user))` and the correct object is logged to the console.
The console output looks like this:
[{"id":6,"first_name":"hello","last_name":"hello","user_name":"hello","user_password":"hello","email":"hello","cooking_experience":"hello"}]

However, if i run `console.log(req.user.id)`, the console logs "undefined"

If i run Object.keys(req.user) the following is logged to the console:
['0']

Comment: The output logged in console is an array with one element. Would you try something like: console.log(req.user[0].id) ?

Comment: That's it! Thank you! You Rock!

Comment: Glad to help, bro.